# Convert/Update a text to another string (dates)

Tags: vb.net

I need to change the format of a string which is in date format like this:

```
Wednesday, 10 April, 2013
```

into

```
10 April 2013
```

What is the best way of achiveing this?, i.e remove the day and commas

Comment: The input value is a string right? Not a date?

Comment: dim foo() as String = Split(dateString,",") : Dim result as String = foo(1) + foo(2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")
```

this will allow you to customize the format as much as you'd like ex.

```
myDate.ToString("dd-MMMM/yyyy")
```

there are also conversions built into .net such as

```
.ToShortDateString()

.ToLongDateString()
```

if the input is a string then you have to convert to a date , then parse back into a formatted string

```
Date.Parse("Wednesday, 10 April, 2013").ToString("dd-MMMM/yyyy")
```

Comment: Good answer. Never thought of changing the format like that. Simple yet effective.

Comment: the last example I gave will work , use Date.Parse , or DateTime.Parse

Comment: Doesn't seem to change the date/string at all, I must be missing something

Comment: I would be careful when parsing string to date. another cultureinfo, and the conversion to date will not work. Either define the cultureinfo, or make sure that never a pc with other cultureinfo will run the code

Comment: @Stan - this code was an example to answer your question , you should always use .TryParse to prevent trying to parse an invalid date , and also set cultureInfo because different countries use different date formats

Answer (score 1):

If the input value is a string then you could to convert to a date and then back to your required format

```
Dim provider As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
Dim dateText = "Wednesday, 10 April, 2013"
Dim dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateText, "dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy", provider)
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Date.Today.ToLongDateString
```